# Use OpenStreetMap as fallback for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I want to develop an application that uses maps functionality but want to maintain compatibility with non-Google Android devices. I want to ask how to use the OpenStreetMap API for Android as a fallback if a device does not support Google Maps API? (Code samples please)

Side question: Are devices with access to Android Market (now Google Play) guaranteed to have access to Google Maps API?

Comment: Maybe you can use http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Comment: I am planning to use that. My question is how can I make it so that if available, it will use Google Maps and only if not, it will fall back to OSM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at any of the pages in the wiki for the OSM projecT?

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/w/list

both "howToUseJar" and "howToUse" seem like they'd be relevant to you.

> Are devices with access to Android Market (now Google Play) guaranteed to have access to Google Maps API?

No,
I know for sure there is atleast 1 device out there with access to Market but does not have Maps application. I imagine there are more too.